# get details with jquery, php and mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

When we click on the candidate get details from mysql db. If i click first candidate I want to see the first candidate details, if I click 2nd I will see 2nd candidate details. Please share code with me how to get details with jquery, php and mysql? I want to listing candidates. When we click on the candidate I want to see the details of the candidate on the right side window.

[image: image here]

Comment: It's good... you've nice idea.. but what have you implemented for it yet?

Comment: Add your code whatever you tried, we are here to solve your bugs not for doing the whole code for you. Hope you understand!

Comment: I want to display the candidates left side when we click on any one of candidate, the right side we need to show that candidate details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a php script to read details from MySQL database
2. After retrieving data from MySQL use Json or xml  & use echo to respond with details
3. In the On click event handler of UI item, make an Ajax call & send the candidate identifier to your php script then parse the response sent
4. Update the UI components based on the data received.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:-

Take a class as header to the header rows, and use nextUntil to fetch all rows beneath the clicked header until the next header.

**JS**

```
$('.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

**Html**

```
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header">
    <td colspan="2">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ty3b/)**

**Another Example:**

```
$('.header').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100); // or just use "toggle()"
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Mdy/)**

You can also use promise to toggle the span icon/text after the toggle is complete in-case of animated toggle.

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100).promise().done(function () {
        $this.find('span').text(function (_, value) {
            return value == '-' ? '+' : '-'
        });
    });
});
```

Or just with a css pseudo element to represent the sign of expansion/collapse, and just toggle a class on the header.

**CSS:-**

```
.header .sign:after{
  content:"+";
  display:inline-block;      
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content:"-";
}
```

**JS:-**

```
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nc8bt9ss/)**